# Responsive Site - Phantom width causing horizontal scroll bar

Tags: jquery, css, width, scrollbar, overflow

I am building myself a portfolio website that is causing me a lot of grief in trying to make it responsive. It didn't start out responsive which was my first mistake but I have gotten so close to making it all work now that I would really appreciate some expert help.

if you go to http://www.moreiradesigns.com and make the width of the browser screen as small as it can go you will immediately see what the problem is.

A horizontal scroll bar appears and grows inversely proportional to the size of the screen. If you scroll right you will see nothing there and you will note that the body ends where it is supposed to.

Any help would be great in diagnosing the problem!

-P.S. It is extremely glaring on any sort of mobile device =(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to what Cyrena said, your `<ul id="Grid">` is set to 100%, its parent is set to 96%, and its great-grandparent `id="portfolio"` is set to 100%, which will all conspire to give you some unwanted width expansion.

Comment: I made those changes so that Portfolio is 100%, Child is 96 and Grid is 95% but problem persists/

Comment: I suggest checking out the 3D view in firefox inspect element.

Comment: Thank you Watson, the 3D view on firefox was able to clarify exactly whats going on there! great tool!

Comment: Yeah, that 3D view is great for stuff like this. Plus it looks really impressive to people/ coworkers who don't know about it ;).

Comment: Thanks to Watson's suggestion of using the Firefox 3D viewer I was able to diagnose that in fact the #footerContainer had a width of 90em on my mobile break points. Setting those to 90% fixed the issue!

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your porftolio download section has a left property set to 520px, which is wider than many small screens.

```css
.portfolioDownload {
  position: absolute;
  width: 0em;
  height: 0em;
  float: left;
  left: 520px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Actually this did help a little bit, I have 3 breaking points on my layout. I changed those attributes on the main desktop breakpoint and that did eliminate the scrollbar for the tablet size but not for the phone size (less than 768)